# Problems involved in Re-creating twitter using Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Me Again

A quick question regarding JpaRepository

I am working on a mirror project of Twitter using Spring boot and Hibernate. I have finished creating most of Twitter's functions - posting, forwarding, commenting, etc. Now I am working to make this web app more user-friendly, particularly regarding the way the app loads posts from the database.

Currently, my app works this way: every time a user logs in, the system will load all posts from his/her "followed list", which is not good because if this user follows hundreds of people there might be tens of thousands of posts being loaded simultaneously - which not only constitutes a huge burden on the server, but also costs the user's patience.

So I want to switch to another way of loading posts. Currently, I have this in mind:

Every time a user logs into the system, there will be a "lastLoginTime", created with `@LastModifiedTime`. Every time someone posts something, there will be an "postTime" created with `@CreatedTime`. Each time a user logs into the system, the server will load posts published no more than 24 hours before the last loginTime.

To be more specific. Suppose I log into the system at 8:00 am. The system is supposed to load posts published AFTER 8:00 am yesterday.

Since I am using JpaRepository. I intend to use @Query to annotate the method. But I just cannot think of a possible way to write a good JPQL to achieve this goal. Can anybody help me with this? I have already finished creating the lastLoginTime and postTime - btw.

Thanks in advance
Sincerely

'

Comment: Any ideas? Struggling

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Hibernate does not have many date functions. So, you need to try to call a native DATE function of your database to do that. Another alternative is always save, in a new column with the post date information one day **before** the original post date.

With the new column, you can just:

```
SELECT post FROM Post post 
WHERE post.postTimeToLoad >= 
    (SELECT user.lastLoginTime FROM User user WHERE user.id = :idLoggerUser)
```

If you can use the native functions from your database, see this MySql example using `DATE_SUB` function:

```
SELECT post FROM Post post 
WHERE DATE(DATE_SUB(post.postTime, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) >= 
    (SELECT user.lastLoginTime FROM User user WHERE user.id = :idLoggerUser)
```